# Find descriptions of products users have bought but not rated MySQL, Join Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the descriptions of products that users have bought but not rated, but I get NULL values for the description, I have the following tables.

customer

```
id  | customer
----|---------
1   | john
2   | jenkins
3   | jane
4   | janet
```

product

```
id  | description
----|---------
1   | deoderant
2   | soap
3   | shampoo
4   | razor
5   | sponge
```

orders

```
customer_id  | product_id
-------------|---------
1            | 1
1            | 2
2            | 3
2            | 4
3            | 5
```

rate

```
customer_id  | product_id | rate
-------------|------------|-------
1            | 1          | 1
2            | 2          | 3
2            | 4          | 3
4            | 2          | 2
```

Here is the SQL query.

```
select description from rate
left join orders on
rate.customer_id = orders.customer_id and rate.product_id = orders.product_id
left join product on
orders.customer_id and product.id
where orders.customer_id is null;
```

The result I get is:

```
description   
-------------
null
null
```

I assume I am going in the right direction and why do I get null or/and is it wrong way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this could work:

```
select 
  product.description 
from 
  orders
  inner join product on 
    product.product_id  = orders.product_id
  inner join customer on 
    customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id
  left join rate on 
    rate.customer_id = orders.customer_id and 
    rate.product_id  = orders.product_id
where
    rate.rate is null
```